# Design an algorithm - Median, computer science

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, median

I was wondering if this question belongs here or on StackOverflow, but it is a question of mathematical nature so this seems more appropriate.

We have an array $S$ of $n$ different numbers $S=a_1,a_2,a_3,...a_n$ where $i \neq j$ implies $a_i \neq a_j$. We know nothing about how the values in the array are arranged. All that we know is that it has $n$ numbers and they are all different. We can also assume that the median is an element in $S$.

We want to find the $k$ values that are closest to the median of the array, and we want to do it in $O(n)$.

Here is my idea that somehow simplifies the question but does not solve it entirely.

We have a method (we call it "Select" algorithm) that finds the median in $O(n)$. So finding the median is no problem and it's obviously something that needs to be done (but only once!), let's call the median $m$ for short.

Now define a new array $S' = a_1-m,a_2-m,a_3-m,...a_n-m$. That took another $n$ calculations so we are still at $O(n)$. Now go through all the elements of $S'$ and multiply by $-1$ the negative elements, another $n$ steps, still $O(n)$.

So now the problem is this: we have an array $S'$ with strictly non negative values. We want to find the $k$ smallest elements. **How is this done in** $O(n)$???

The naive approach would be to find the minimum ($n-1$ steps), remove it from the array, find the minimum again ($n-2$ steps) and so on, but that is $n-1+n-2+n-3+...+n-k-1$ but when $k$ approaches $n$, that approach will be $O(n^2)$ so that's no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know $m$, in $O(n)$ time you can compute the array $B$ of values $|a_i - m|$ for each data element.  Now you want the $k$ least of these, where $1 \le k \le n$.  For some $s$, these will be the ones where $|a_i - m| \le s$.  It would be easiest if $k$ was $n/2$: you could find $s$ by another application of your median algorithm.  By the title "Select", I suspect that this algorithm does something more general than median-finding.  But if median-finding is all you can do, you can accomplish it by adding in some "dummy" values that are either negative or greater than the maximum.

Comment: Allow me to clarify, "Select" is an algorithm that gets an array $A$ and a value $i$ and it returns the value $a \in A$ such that there are $i-1$ elements in $A$ that are smaller than $a$. But that algorithm demands that all the values of $A$ are strictly different from one another.

Comment: @Oria: If the only thing preventing you from applying the "Select" algorithm is that some of the values in $S'$ may be identical, then instead of replacing every negative element $x$ with $-x$, you can replace a positive $x$ with $2x$ and a negative $x$ with $-2x-1$.